# Can't connect to mysql database with ssh client

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection-string

I want to connect trough SSH channel to mysql database on the server.

I have downloaded this [SSH.Net](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) library.

This is what I have tried and I thought it will work after my secured connection has been established.

My SSH connection is established but normal connection to database is not executed.

So check my code please:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("cpanel****", "******", "******"))
          {
            client.Connect();
            con = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            con.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("insert into {0} values (null, ?Parname , ?Parname2, ?Parname3, ?Parname4, ?Parname5, ?Parname6, ?Parname7);", ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main")), con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?Parname", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = Math.Round(deciLat, 5);
            // ... more parameters
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            client.Disconnect();
           }
```

Comment: It gives you any error? The `connection string` is correct?

Comment: yes connection string is correct. I am using the same one for the mysql workbench to see my database. It gives me timeout error. I have tried before to connect to server only trough normal link and server gives me timeout but when connecting with an ssh channel it is working. I am not sure if this actually opens a ssh channel so I can use it or I need an additional parameters to show it to connection string if you understand me. You can check this library and let me say what you think.

Comment: I may be missing something... how is MySqlConnection going to know about the SshClient?

Comment: Well yes that is exactly what the problem is. I don't know how to combine those two as I thought that channel will be open and I can use it but as you can see I can't. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial http://georgelantz.com/2007/09/10/access-mysql-through-ssh-tunnel-in-a-windows-net-application/ which sounds reasonable.

Basic idea is to establish an SSH connection with a tunnel (aka port forwarding) and then point your MySQL connection to localhost.

SSH tunnel redirects connections to localhost:XX to the ssh server port:YY.  So your port YY will be the mysql connection port, and in your connection string you would use localhost:XX.

The SSH library you are using also seems to support port forwarding, so you might be able to get that working as well.

Comment: thank you for that link I will try it. Can you see this source code from which I took part for opening ssh channel which is btw. working only need to figure out how to insert my mysql requests: http://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16341#143028

Comment: You want to take a look at this http://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16341#143026 how they are doing port forwarding.

Comment: I am not quite understanding this port forwarding. Why do I need localhost in any of these parameters? My database is on the server why would I need to forward it. In the program that you have mentioned. In the remote port I need to put 3306 as mysql is 3306, but I don't know my ssh port and localport, can you give me a hand please

Comment: Well, the reason you need ssh in the first place is that your mysql server is behind firewall, so you can't just connect to it.  You need to establish a secure ssh connection and then forward packets via it (secure tunnel).  Your db client doesn't know anything about ssh.  Your ssh client doesn't know anything about MySQL.  What ssh client can do is open up a server port locally and forward connections to it to a server running on the server end of the ssh connection.  So what you are doing is asking SSH client to forward connections to localhost:XX to sshserver:YY.  XX and YY can be same.

Comment: I keep getting authentication error and my info is correct, I'll mark you as answer as you helped me and gave me a solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11952/discussion-between-denonth-and-mk)